# генерация строки из массива случайной длины

Tags: php

Описать класс, который при выполнении `echo new MyClass();` 
вернет строку вида:

```
{"key-0":"0","key-1":"1","key-2":"2"}
```

**замечание**: весь процесс генерации выполнить без создания промежуточных переменных. 
Строка должна быть cгенерирована из массива случайной длины от **10** до **20**

Comment: см. "магический" метод `__toString`. Дальше сами, сами.

Comment: Как автор данной задачи, хочу сказать, что приложенный выше ответ в корне не правильный, т.к. не выполняет условие: "весь процесс генерации выполнить без создания промежуточных переменных.". Свойства внутри класса так же считаются промежуточными переменными. Решение укладывается буквально в 3 строчки кода...

Comment: "Как автор данной задачи"- что вы имеете ввиду? Вы желаете дать ответ или это только комментарий? Это поле служит только для ответов.

Comment: Данная задача была описана мной для собеседование соискателей на позицию php разработчика :)

Comment: Тогда вам надо задать вопрос на [мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), если вы считаете, что ваш кандидат использовал плагиат. А так же вы можете кнопкой "тревога" привлечь внимание модераторов.  Если кандидат имеет право  публиковать вашу задачу, дайте развёрнутый ответ, где укажите на недостатки.

Comment: @Bart, формально поле класса не является переменной.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вроде как суть задания - показать свои знания php... тем более, как писал выше, решение укладывается буквально в 3 строчки кода

Comment: @Bart, скорее всего map? Но использовать поле класса вместо переменной - тоже оригинальный вариант.

Comment: @Qwertiy, о чем мы спорим?

Comment: @Bart, да я, вроде, не спорю.

Comment: @Bart Большое спасибо за задачу! Чем больше интересных задач будут в открытом доступе и чем больше разнообразных решений к ним будут предложено, тем более глубокие знания будут у сообщества. Если у вас есть и другие интересные задачки, пожалуйста, опубликуйте их на сайте!

Comment: @Bart, а про мой вариант что скажешь?

Comment: @Qwertiy, много лишней логики

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyClass
{
    public $array1 = array();
    function __toString()
    {
        while((count($this->array1) < 11 or rand(0,1) > .5) and count($this->array1) < 21)
        {
            $this->array1['key-'.count($this->array1)] = (string)count($this->array1);
        }
        return json_encode($this->array1);
    }
}

echo new MyClass();
```

Comment: Описание классов в PHP начинаются служебным словом class.

Comment: И, эм, по условию вы сами должны сгенерировать массив случайной длины. Непорядок. Подумайте ещё над ответом. Пока у вас неправильно.

Comment: Исправил, и даже добавил что бы значения выводились в двойных кавычках как в вопросе, ооп вижу впервые

Comment: Снял свой минус.

Comment: Да, вот теперь хорошо. Поставил плюс.

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/YxuNdl

```
<?php

class MyClass {
  function __toString() {
    return "{" . implode(",", array_map(function ($i)  {
      return "\"key-$i\":\"$i\"";
    }, array_keys(array_fill(0, rand(1,32), 0)))) . "}";
  }
}

echo new MyClass();
```